# subtraction on large double has no effect

Tags: c, double

I'm using the standard formula for calculating the min/max of a data type (in this case integers) but I can't achieve accuracy on numbers that should be LONG_MAX or ULONG_MAX. The rightmost subtraction in my formula seems to have no effect when subtracting small values.

Eg., I am subtracting 1, but even changing the value to be 26 does not change the value assigned to my variable.

On my computer: 2^64 = 2^64-1 = 2^64-26. What is causing this behaviour and how can I get the expected value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void calcRange(short);

/* print min and max of data types */
int main() {

    printf("CHAR:\n");
    calcRange(sizeof(char));
    printf("SHORT:\n");
    calcRange(sizeof(short));
    printf("INT:\n");
    calcRange(sizeof(int));
    printf("LONG:\n");
    calcRange(sizeof(long));

}

/* calculates the range of a data type given it's size in bytes */
void calcRange(short size) {

    double lower = -pow(2, size*8 - 1);           
    double upper = pow(2, size*8 - 1) - 1;  // change rightmost sub
    double uUpper = pow(2, size*8) - 1;     // change rightmost sub

    printf("The signed range for this data type is (%.0f , %.0f)\n", lower, upper);
    printf("The unsigned range for this data type is (0, %.0f)\n\n", uUpper);

}
```

Comment: Analogously to the linked duplicate, you *could* try `long double`. Would probably be better to not try this kind of calculation with a floating point type at all.

Comment: The calculations are wrong in the general case anyways, as they assume a lot of things (8-bit `char`, no padding in `int`, ...). Just use the constants defined in `limits.h`, there's a reason for them.